# How to reserved destination value when source value is null in AutoMapper 6?

Tags: c#, automapper

First of all, English is not my mother tongue, so please excuse me.

Source Model:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Destination Model:

```
public class Task2
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<Task, Task2>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName))
    .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
```

And now, the problem is:

```
Task t = new Task(){
    Id = 0,
    Title = "blablabla",
    FirstName = null,
    LastName = null
}
Task2 t2 = new Task2(){
    Id = 0,
    Title = "blablabla",
    UserName = "Foo Bar"
}
Task2 tt = Mapper.Map<Task, Task2>(t, t2);
```

After Mapping, the `tt.UserName` will be Empty.
I want to keep the value of `Task2.UserName`, but it seems doesn't work. How Can I do?

Comment: If you don't want to map anything to `UserName`, then why have you configured the mapper to map it? Also, your condition ignores `null` values but it looks to me that your source value can never be null (though I'm not 100% sure how AutoMapper works!).

Comment: Note that test sample is not very good - you have same id and same title. It's hard to see that mapping actually happens

Answer (score 4):

You can put condition to member configuration expression:

```
   .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opt => {
       opt.Condition(s => s.FirstName != null && s.LastName != null); // condition here
       opt.MapFrom(s => s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName);
   }); // remove all members condition
```

Note that possibly you should check not only for `null` but for empty values as well using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhitespace`

Output:

```
{
  "Id": 0,
  "Title": "blablabla",
  "UserName": "Foo Bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case your `FirstName` and `LastName` are `null`, then the `srcMember` will be a space - `" "`. As a result, your condition is matched.

You either need to change your projection to return `null` in the case both parts are `null`, or you need to change your condition to match the space.